# Does it take more energy to evaporate a litre of water in a vacuum, and if so, why?

Tags: thermodynamics, water, vacuum, evaporation

I got this information and want to know if it is correct and if so, why does it take more energy to evaporate water in a vacuum compared to no vacuum?

#### Vacuum:

it takes 4200 J/kg to increase the temp of water by 1°C, so 1 kg of water  needs  ((50°C-25°C)×4200 J) = 105 kJ of energy to be brought from 25°C to 50°C. Then, to evaporate entirely that kg of water you need 2386 kJ, so about 23 times the amount of heating up energy. Total energy (2386+105) =2491 kJ

#### Atmospheric

it takes 4200 J/kg to increase the temp of water by 1°C, so 1 kg of water  needs  ((100°C-25°C)×4200 J) =315 kJ of energy to be brought from 25°C to 100°C. Then, to evaporate entirely that kg of water you need 2260kj, so about 7 times the amount of heating up energy. Total energy ( 2260 + 315) is 2575kj

Comment: I'm not sure how you got your question from your quote. 105kJ/kg in vacuum and 315kJ/kg in atmosphere is decidedly less energy in a vacuum.

Comment: Can you say where you got this information from  ? I think , it would be the other way around, it would take LESS energy for water to evaporate in a vacuum, not more energy

Comment: What is the significance of the temperatures in your question--25C, 50C, and 100C? Remember that water does not need to boil in order to evaporate. Evaporation happens when the [_vapor pressure_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vapor_pressure) of water at some temperature is greater than the _partial pressure of water vapor_ in the surrounding atmosphere, and [boiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boiling_point) happens when the vapor pressure is greater than the _total pressure_ of the surrounding atmosphere.

Comment: Water will happily boil all the way down to 0 Celsius in a vacuum, no extra energy required. The heat of the water pays for the phase change until it freezes (then it will begin to sublimate rather than evaporate). It'll also evaporate on its own heat (but not boil) slowly in atmosphere, as when your dishes dry etc.

Comment: @AndyNewman - less energy to get to boiling point at 50°C, but comparatively more energy needed to maintain evaporation than it took to reach boiling point.

Comment: @SolomonSlow the significance of temperature is that water will boil at a lower temperature (say 50C) at some vacuum - so it takes less heat (energy) to get to the boiling point and force evaporation. But then, according to my source of information, and counter intuitively, it does not take much less energy to maintain this boil and completely evaporate the water than it does at standard atmosphere. So I'm trying to understand why ~23 times more energy is required to maintain the boil than needed to initially get the boil, while only roughly x7 times more at standard atmosphere.

Comment: @silverrahul - I am asking because I agree with you - it would seem to be the other way round. My source of information is a manufacturer of vacuum boilers.

Comment: Can we clarify - are we maintaining a boil _in_ a vacuum, or in a container which _was_ a vacuum when we started the evaporation process but is now filling with vapour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The boiling temperature of water depends on the pressure that it is made to boil at.  Due to this, water will boil at a broad range of temperatures, up to its critical temperature of 374 deg C, at a pressure of 217.7 atmospheres, which is the critical temperature and critical pressure respectively.

If you run an experiment whereby you place 1 liter of water into a 2 liter closed container, and make sure that only water vapor fills the vapor space, you will find that the density of the liquid water and water vapor vary with temperature.  As the temperature goes up, the liquid density goes down (as expected) and the vapor density goes up because the vapor pressure of the water increases with temperature, causing more water to evaporate into the vapor phase (i.e., the pressure increases).  This effect continues until the critical point, where the liquid density and the vapor density become equal.  At the critical temperature and above, only one phase of water exists in the container (a supercritical phase).  Obviously, you can't boil water at this point because separate liquid and vapor phases no longer exist.  This means that the heat of vaporization of water vanishes at the critical point.

So, to answer the question "does it take more energy to evaporate a liter of water in a vacuum, and if so why?", note that the heat of vaporization of water becomes zero at the critical point.  As the pressure and temperature of the above referenced container are moved down from the critical point, the heat of vaporization of water increases.  Because evaporation at low pressure conditions (i.e., vacuum conditions) occurs at low temperatures, it takes more energy to evaporate a given amount of water than it does at standard conditions (e.g., 1 atmosphere).  As counter-intuitive as it sounds, evaporating (aka boiling) water at vacuum conditions occurs at a low temperature, but it requires more heat to evaporate a given amount of water under those conditions.  However, note one caveat: this conclusion is based only on evaporating (aka boiling) the water at a constant temperature, meaning that the water is already at its boiling point and there is no heating to get it to its boiling point.  If such heating is required, you would need to specify a starting temperature for the water, several final temperatures (or pressures) that you are interested in, and evaluate each situation to determine the total amount of heat required.

Comment: Thank you... I have a feeling you know what yo are talking about. But you said: "As counter-intuitive as it sounds, evaporating (aka boiling) water at vacuum conditions occurs at a low temperature, but it requires more heat to evaporate a given amount of water under those conditions". Isn't that the same as saying, At lower heat, you need more heat to do the job? Counter intuitive is an understatement :-)

Comment: @Owen "temperature" does not mean the same thing as "heat." Heat is easy to explain: Heat is equivalent to energy when we're talking the language of thermodynamics. Temperature is trickier: I'm not a physicist, and I maybe won't get it quite right, but it's proportional to something along the lines of the average kinetic energy of the molecules of the substance.

Comment: @Owen, "more heat to evaporate..." means, more _energy_ to break the bonds that keep H2O molecules close to each other in liquid water. If the molecules don't have much kinetic energy (low temperature), then it makes sense that it would take more energy to pull them apart. Above the critical temperature that David White spoke of, they already have enough energy to break apart from each other without needing any extra heat added.

Comment: @Owen, bear with me a bit.  In my opinion, the common use of the English language tends to lead to physics misconceptions.  Heat is not "hot" ... it's energy.  Temperature tells you how concentrated that energy is, but a Joule is a Joule is a Joule, no matter what temperature exists.  That concept is difficult to accept because "everybody knows" that heat is hot (hopefully, you get my allusion regarding this statement).  And to answer your first sentence, yes, I know what I'm talking about.  I have a master's degree in chemical engineering, and I have 21 years of industrial experience.

Answer (score 0):

the boiling point of water depends from the pressure, so in vacuum water will evaporate at any temperature,

Comment: Water evaporates just fine at STP, as the towels in the bathroom can attest to.

Comment: This is not quite correct. Water evaporates at temperatures way below 100°C even in the atmosphere. Also, this does not answer the question at all.

Comment: you are right I should have said boil instead of evaporate.